# How to make a chat website with Delphi7 and HTTP

Tags: delphi, http, delphi-7

I want to make a small HTTP chat website working with a Delphi 7 web Server. I have no idea how to approach this. I have searched on the internet for hours but I found nothing helpful. I have setup a basic Delphi 7 web server. The reason I want to use Delphi is because I'm most familiar with it and I want to use HTTP because that's the only language I know to how use in a browser.  Could I do this and is there any tutorial on how to do this somewhere on the internet?  I wanted to make a chat server because it seemed like a challenge. The help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Step 1.  Start with something simpler!  Really your biting off more than you can chew here.  What have you written with Delphi before?  Have you set up a Delphi 7 web server?  Why Delphi? Why a chat server?  How sophisticated an app have you previously created.  We need more infor

Comment: @TobyAllen I edited my question to answer your question.

Comment: Too broad! Start with something smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as I love Delphi, I would strongly recommend learning another language for this task.

PHP is very easy to get into. All you need is notepad to type a file with this:

```
<?php echo "hello" ?>
```

And you have a working web application that shows hello. With delphi it gets more complicated. You either need to provide your own web server, or you need to create a .dll that plugs into your browser, and you'll need a lot more code to get something simple.

PHP also has good mysql support built in, which you'll probably need if you're going to create a chat page, because it can easily deal with multi-user issues for you.

I know this doesn't answer your question about how to do this with Delphi, but please take this advice.

Comment: Ok, downvotes were expected. I'm willing to take them if it helps to push somebody in the right direction.